# Finding a folder in a large structure on a mounted NFS share

Tags: linux, search, nfs

Imagine you need to find a folder using some pattern, like you do with find.

```
find . -iname "*foo*"
```

However in a situation with a mounted NFS share with large number of items it is very time-consuming, sometimes you get a "broken pipe" error.

Is there a better way to find a folder using a search pattern for its name?

Comment: Why not run the `find` on the NFS server?

Comment: no access to the server.

Comment: Then using `find . -type d -iname '*foo*'` is your best option - you will run into performance limits of NFS metadata handling, but since NFS is the only thing you have this is as good as it gets.